# Create Multiple Campaign From MYSQL Query

Tags: google-ads-api

have a MYSQL database and I would like to add new campaign for each row I have in the MYSQL table.
The code below creates only one campaign, but I want to create multiple campaigns e.g. each row in the table should be used to create new campaign, please advise.

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    // Create a campaign with required and optional settings.
    $campaign = new Campaign();
    $campaign->setName($row["name"]. uniqid());
    $campaign->setAdvertisingChannelType(AdvertisingChannelType::SEARCH);



    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with the above code?

Comment: It create one campaign, and that's it. While the actual table contains more than 50 rows so I expect to see 50+ campaigns.

Comment: If you just do `var_dump($row)` inside your while loop does it print 50+ records?

Comment: Yes it does. it prints 50+ rows.